# Xcode 6 iOS Simulator (iPad2, iPhone5) now Release Mode now running x86_64. Debug i386

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode6

Just noticed the Simulator for the devices that do not run arm64 (so iPhone4/5, iPad 2, which should be running i386 simulator) runs x86_64 in the simulator for release mode now in Xcode 6 by default.
To clarify: Debug mode still calls i386 for these simulator targets... so weird.

Noted in the build log:

```
clang++ -arch x86_64
```

This is a bit of an issue testing for older projects that only compiled vs the old i386/i686 architecture for release mode.

Anyone have any idea how to make it run in i386 for release as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution!!!

Set Build Active Architecture Only to Yes

[image: Solution: Use Build Active Architecture Only to Yes]