# Does Xcode 6 Simulator use x86_64?

Tags: ios, xcode6, ios-simulator

Sorry to have to ask this. This relates to [Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 when building for ARM64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28043785/608639), but I only have Xcode 4 and 5 for testing.

Does Xcode 6 use x86_64 for the iOS simulator?

---

This seems to be related: [Xcode 6 iOS Simulator (iPad2, iPhone5) now Release Mode now running x86_64. Debug i386](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26033299). But I can't quite make out the finer points the person asking the question is making.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends. It uses `x86_64` when building for a 64-bit simulated device. It uses `i386` when building for a 32-bit simulated device.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy. So I'm clear when Xcode 6 is being used... When I build a fat library for iOS using the SDK from the command line, then I should include ARMv7 (device), ARMv7s (device), ARM64 (device), i386 (simulator) and x86_64 (simulator) architectures? Is that correct?

Comment: This is interesting... I just built a test app under Xcode 5/iOS 7 for ARM64 - iPad Retina (64-bit) Simulator. It used i386: `Non-fat file: .../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-test-fnfmgifegrbmzffiwuillterfkcp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ios-test.app/ios-test is architecture: i386`. So Xcode 6 did indeed change if the information in your answer is accurate.

Comment: This is interesting, too... I can build it with Xcode 5/iOS 7 by using `-miphoneos-version-min=8`.