# iOS - XCODE - Build failing due to openssl

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, build, openssl

i have setted my project's build settings inserting "Standard architectures (armv7, arm64)" and "Valid architecture (armv7, armv7s and arm64)" for . With these options i can build the project for iPhone 3Gs, iPhone 5 and iPhone 5s (hardware with 32 and 64 bit architecture) but i have problems when i try to build the project for the simulator. Why? I have errors like this

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
 "_BIO_f_base64", referenced from:
```

Answer (score 2):

It is due to OpenSSL library

## Solution 1:

- Project settings
- Select Target
- Select the `General` tab
- Under `Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content`, click on the plus button.
- Find the `OpenSSL.xcframework` from the list and hit Add.
- select `Embed and sign` from `OpenSSL.xcframework`
- run xcode build again

## Solution 2:

1. add this line into Podfile

```
pod 'OpenSSL-Universal', :modular_headers => true, :configurations => ['Release']
```

2. just run `pod install` in the ios root directory
3. run the build

## Solution 3:

For whatever reason in `Project settings > Select Target > Build Settings > Framework Search Paths` this:

[image: Screenshot 2023-04-07 at 9 45 48 PM]

but the Release ones were missing a bunch of those so I added these 2:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/OpenSSL-Universal/Frameworks"
"${PODS_XCFRAMEWORKS_BUILD_DIR}/OpenSSL-Universal"
```

Then both debug and release builds worked for me.

Comment: When running `pod install` after the second solution I got this warning `[!] There are duplicate dependencies on OpenSSL-Universal in Podfile:

- OpenSSL-Universal
- OpenSSL-Universal (= 1.1.1100)` is it normal??

Answer (score 0):

That's because the simulator is running on an i386 architecture and no arm.
Add something like i386 to the supported architecture. (see [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26033299/4206060) of the many answers here on SO for details and screenshots)

Answer (score 0):

BIO_f_base64 is part of OpenSSL (https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_f_base64.html).  That is not available on iOS.  Are you embedding a local copy of OpenSSL into your app?  It looks like you might not be building the library correctly.  Make sure you build it for the iOS Simulator and x86_64 plus i386.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the command that "lipo -info openssl.a" in terminal.
Watch what is it'architecture?  should be arm.